# Glitches installing wxpython?

Tags: package, wxpython, conda

Im relatively new to python world.

Im trying to install wxpython on several computers and it keeps failing.
I use anaconda version 4.9.2 and use the prompt command:

conda install -c anaconda wxpython

I get the following error message:

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
> Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

I try updating python to latest version. I try a number of things. and still I get this pesky problem. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Nothing wrong *per se*.** Those messages are indicating that Conda can't install that package without changing the currently installed packages. Because the Anaconda distribution (!= Conda) has lots of packages this happens very frequently. Also, this particular package is not updated frequently and the **anaconda** channel doesn't even seem to keep pace with that.

In general, it is better practice is to create new environments for each project/task you have to work on, and only install the packages you require. Also, the **conda-forge** channel tends to be a more consistent provider for packages, but undergoes less interoperability testing and tuning than the Anaconda channel packages. That is, consider trying something like

```bash
conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge python=3.9 wxpython ...
```

where `myenv` is whatever you would like to refer to the environment as, and `...` should be whatever other packages you know you would like to use.